# rails model class with multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking a way to implement a multiple role for a class Address (BillingAddress, ShippingAddress e.t.c) by avoiding using a second table address_roles to my project. Is there any possible way?

My Address model below :

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.inheritance_column = nil
    serialize :roles
    attr_accessible :street, :number, :postal, :city, :country

end

class InstallationAddress < Address
end

class BillingAddress < Address
end

class ShippingAddress < Address
end
```

I would like to be able to save roles as an Array such as ["BillingAddress", "InstallationAddress"]

**Edit 1:** How should I describe it in my model in order to work? For example how InstallationAddress.all is going to return me only the addresses that have role InstallationAddress or if I have a belong_to :user , how user.installation_address will be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

What you have tried is almost correct. is'nt it..? 
1) Add a new column "roles" in the Address model. 
2) Make roles as serializable in address model (what you have already written). 
3) Include a multiple select dropdown in your view page, where you want to place a dropdown.

```
<%= form.select :roles,
                        [["BillingAddress","BillingAddress"], ["InstallationAddress","InstallationAddress"]],
                        :prompt => "Select Roles",
                        :multiple => true
%>
```

You need not to have any new model for address_roles. And, I am sorry if you are not expecting the way like this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah., I too was not much clear with your question. But, I answered with some assumptions. Please, dont hesitate to make your question much clear. I will try to answer you if i know. Thanks!!